# Using eventjs with angularjs not working

Tags: jquery, events, angularjs

Greetings Overflowers,

Using angularjs bind function to register event handlers on elements does not work when including [eventjs](https://github.com/mudcube/Event.js) script!

I was under the impression that eventjs will replace default addEventListener function to its own which will be used by angularjs bind function seamlessly.

I tried incuding eventjs before and after angularjs but no luck.

Any ideas?

Kind regards

Comment: Can you point us to the docs for "angularjs bind function". Thanks.

Comment: search for bind in http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.element

Comment: why negative vote without comment!!!

Comment: have you tried something? what have you done so far?

Comment: I tried to include the eventjs javascript into my page which should replace the elements default add/removeEventListener functions (as per thier docs and code, and you can take a look) that are used by angularjs and hence angularjs bind function would seemlessly use eventjs without any further changes, however this is not the case as events stop firing and I do not know why? I am testing on latest Chrome.

Comment: Using eventjs direct functions still works and events are fired.

Comment: I've never used event.js but perhaps adding something like angular-ui's event utility might help. https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-utils/blob/master/modules/event/event.js

Comment: where did you read about event.js overriding addEventListener?

Comment: I already have a generic event directive for angularjs. I need eventjs because it has fantastic advanced touch event handling that suites my needs. Also I do not need to deal differently with other events as eventjs takes care of all, hence achieving consistency. If you follow the link provided in the question, you can read "Retains "this" attribute as target, and overrides native addEventListener" in that page. Also, take a look into thier code and it is clearly overriding the default add/removeEventListener functions for HTML elements.

Comment: The word count comments in which you are describing the context is more than the word count in the original question. Please put detailed data, what you have done so far and what you are getting, with relevant code.

Comment: I think all what you need in the question and comments already. It is either you know a solution or not.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the event message becomes something angular does not expect.
(I do not know the detail, I'll wait for a better answer from the community...)

Just a simple workaround, it would work if you use jQuery (source it before angularJs)

Comment: I do not need jQuery so I am not going to use it.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get the events to bind but I soon discovered that some events don't work using `angular.element.bind()`. For example, in the case of the `click` event, I had to use the `Event.add()` syntax.

Here is what it looks like:

```
angular.module('myApp', []).config(function(){
  Event.modifyEventListener = true; 
  Event.modifySelectors = true; 
}).controller('SomeCtrl', function($scope){
  $scope.eventType = "";
}).directive('foo', function($log){
  return {
    link: function(scope, elm, attr){
      // here it is using the 'bind' syntax
      elm.bind('mousedown mouseup mouseenter mouseleave', function(evt){
        $log.debug(evt);
        scope.eventType = evt.type;
        scope.$apply();
      });
      // here it is using Event.add
      Event.add(elm[0], 'click', function(evt, context) {
        $log.debug(context);
        scope.gesture = context.gesture + ', ' + context.pointerType;
        scope.$apply();
      });
    }
  };
});
```

You can see a demo here: http://plnkr.co/edit/FLMckw?p=preview

Comment: It buys me advanced handling of touch events. Plus, you are looking into a different library. The question is about eventjs by mudcube. Please, follow the link in the question.

Comment: well that makes a lot more sense... I will attempt to update my answer.